# Conformance to a protocol (or base class) specified as a generic type constraint in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

Consider this (invalid) Swift function signature.

```
func f<T, P>(type: T.Type, as alias: P.Type) where T: P
```

This does not compile. Is there any way to achieve conformance to a protocol or base class that is not known beforehand, e.g.,

```
f(type: Bool.self, as: CustomStringConvertible.self)
```

In this case, the first type `T` would have to conform to the second type `P`.

I think this is not currently possible, but I'd love confirmation.

The workaround would be to perform the conformance check at runtime.

Comment: No, all type checks happen at compile time done by the static type system, so all (generic) types need to be known at compile time. The only exception of course when masking exact types using `Any` or when interacting with Obj-C code.

Comment: I'm curious, what would you need this for?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Yes, this is exactly what I thought.

Comment: @Alexander I primarily need it to satisfy my curiosity. I'm always trying to push the limits of the type system. But I've written a dependency resolver and it would be mildly useful in some convenience overloads for registering dependencies: https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/blob/swift4/Guise/Registration.swift (This code is pre-release for v5.0.)